# Unity3D 2020.3.15f2 — Error when building IL2CPP (Windows 11)

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, windows-11

I'm getting an error when building a Unity Project with IL2CPP that I'm having a hard time figuring out:

I had a few errors leading up to this, but after adding the C++ Game libraries to Visual Studio 2022, clearing the IL2CPP cache and ensuring the "Compiler Configuration" is not set to Master... well this shows up.

Am I missing anything obvious here?

I remember an issue in our game before where we had a huge hard-coded array that IL2CPP couldn't handle; but that's been taken care of, and the exact same project builds just fine on another device.

```
D:\.Data\Unity\CinQ\Library\Il2cppBuildCache\Windows\x64\il2cppOutput\Generics67.cpp(32375) : fatal error C1001: Internal compiler error.
(compiler file 'd:\a01\_work\4\s\src\vctools\Compiler\Utc\src\p2\main.c', line 220)
To work around this problem, try simplifying or changing the program near the locations listed above.
If possible please provide a repro here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com
Please choose the Technical Support command on the Visual C++
Help menu, or open the Technical Support help file for more information
  cl!RaiseException()+0x6c
  cl!RaiseException()+0x6c
  cl!InvokeCompilerPassW()+0x7da8b
  cl!InvokeCompilerPassW()+0x11d325

Invocation was: Executable: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\bin\HostX64\x64\cl.exe"
Arguments: "D:\.Data\Unity\CinQ\Library\Il2cppBuildCache\Windows\x64\il2cppOutput\Generics67.cpp" /nologo /c /bigobj /W3 /Z7 /EHs /GR- /Gy /utf-8 /wd4102 /wd4800 /wd4056 /wd4190 /wd4723 /wd4467 /wd4503 /wd4996 /wd4200 /wd4834 /Ox /Oi /Oy- /GS- /Gw /GF /Zo /Yupch-cpp.hpp /Fp"D:\.Data\Unity\CinQ\Library\il2cpp_cache\606504B0802361776F234EA9FE0A85B8.pch" /MT /DNET_4_0 /DUNITY_AOT /DIL2CPP_MONO_DEBUGGER_DISABLED /DGC_NOT_DLL /DRUNTIME_IL2CPP /DBASELIB_INLINE_NAMESPACE=il2cpp_baselib /D_WIN32 /DWIN32 /DWIN32_THREADS /D_WINDOWS /DWINDOWS /D_UNICODE /DUNICODE /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /D_WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS /DNOMINMAX /D_NDEBUG /DNDEBUG /DWINDOWS_SDK_BUILD_VERSION=22000 /DWINAPI_FAMILY=WINAPI_FAMILY_DESKTOP_APP /I"D:\.Data\Unity\2020.3.15f2\Editor\Data\il2cpp\libil2cpp" /I"D:\.Data\Unity\2020.3.15f2\Editor\Data\il2cpp\libil2cpp" /I"D:\.Data\Unity\2020.3.15f2\Editor\Data\il2cpp\external\bdwgc\include" /I"D:\.Data\Unity\2020.3.15f2\Editor\Data\il2cpp\external\xxHash" /I"D:\.Data\Unity\2020.3.15f2\Editor\Data\il2cpp\external\baselib\Include" /I"D:\.Data\Unity\2020.3.15f2\Editor\Data\il2cpp\external\baselib\Platforms\Windows\Include" /I"D:\.Data\Unity\2020.3.15f2\Editor\Data\il2cpp\libil2cpp\pch" /I"D:\.Data\Unity\CinQ\Library\Il2cppBuildCache\Windows\x64\il2cppOutput" /I"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\include" /I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22000.0\shared" /I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22000.0\um" /I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22000.0\winrt" /I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt" /Fo"D:\.Data\Unity\CinQ\Library\il2cpp_cache\7E6CEC28F79AE538C3E2697846E23077.obj" /Fd"D:\.Data\Unity\CinQ\Library\il2cpp_cache\7E6CEC28F79AE538C3E2697846E23077.pdb"
EnvArg key: PATH value: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22000.0\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22000.0\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\bin\HostX64\x64

   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.BuildAllCppFiles(IEnumerable`1 sourceFilesToCompile, IBuildStatisticsCollector statisticsCollector)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.Build(IBuildStatistics& statistics)
   at il2cpp.Compilation.CompilationDriver.Run(RuntimePlatform platform, BuildingOptions buildingOptions, ReadOnlyCollection`1 matchedAssemblyMethodSourceFiles)
   at il2cpp.Program.DoRun(String[] args, RuntimePlatform platform, BuildingOptions buildingOptions, Boolean throwExceptions)
UnityEditorInternal.Runner.RunProgram (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, System.String exe, System.String args, System.String workingDirectory, UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser) (at <44c3723143904fb88deebc993c7bb491>:0)
UnityEditorInternal.Runner.RunManagedProgram (System.String exe, System.String args, System.String workingDirectory, UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser, System.Action`1[T] setupStartInfo) (at <44c3723143904fb88deebc993c7bb491>:0)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.RunIl2CppWithArguments (System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] arguments, System.Action`1[T] setupStartInfo) (at <44c3723143904fb88deebc993c7bb491>:0)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.ConvertPlayerDlltoCpp (UnityEditor.Il2Cpp.Il2CppBuildPipelineData data) (at <44c3723143904fb88deebc993c7bb491>:0)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.Run () (at <44c3723143904fb88deebc993c7bb491>:0)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPUtils.RunIl2Cpp (System.String stagingAreaData, UnityEditorInternal.IIl2CppPlatformProvider platformProvider, System.Action`1[T] modifyOutputBeforeCompile, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry runtimeClassRegistry) (at <44c3723143904fb88deebc993c7bb491>:0)
DesktopStandalonePostProcessor.RunIL2CPP (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditorInternal.IIl2CppPlatformProvider il2cppPlatformProvider, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] cppPlugins) (at <44c3723143904fb88deebc993c7bb491>:0)
DesktopStandalonePostProcessor.SetupStagingArea (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[T] filesToNotOverwrite) (at <44c3723143904fb88deebc993c7bb491>:0)
DesktopStandalonePostProcessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at <44c3723143904fb88deebc993c7bb491>:0)
Rethrow as BuildFailedException: Exception of type 'UnityEditor.Build.BuildFailedException' was thrown.
DesktopStandalonePostProcessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at <44c3723143904fb88deebc993c7bb491>:0)
UnityEditor.Modules.DefaultBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <44c3723143904fb88deebc993c7bb491>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <44c3723143904fb88deebc993c7bb491>:0)
UnityEditor.BuildPipeline:BuildPlayer(String[], String, BuildTarget, BuildOptions)
DLS.CinQ.Build.CinQBuilderBase:BuildZoneServer(String, String, BuildTarget, BuildOptions, String) (at Assets/_Scripts/Build/Editor/CinQBuilderBase.cs:102)
DLS.CinQ.Build.CinQBuilder_LocalDev:BuildZoneServer() (at Assets/_Scripts/Build/Editor/CinQBuilder_LocalDev.cs:91)
DLS.CinQ.Build.Editor.CinQBuilderWindows:OnGUI() (at Assets/_Scripts/Build/Editor/CinQBuilderWindows.cs:61)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)
```

Comment: Solved over on the [Unity Forums](https://forum.unity.com/threads/error-when-building-il2cpp-2020-3-15f2-windows-11.1245958/).

The issue was that Visual Studio needed both the `Desktop development with C++` and `Linux and embedded development with C++` workloads installed in order to build using IL2CPP for both Windows and Linux.